# Plugin.Geolocator (partially) uses coarse locations in Android 12

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-gps, geolocator

I have a tracking app which uses Plugin.Geolocator (4.6.2-beta) to sample locations, as the user moves. This worked perfectly until upgrading to android 12. Now it jumps from the true location to nearby wifi locations and then back to true gps postions and so on, while tracking inside a city.

The app is requesting, and the user allows, fine location. It generally works, but every so often the location jumps abruptly to a nearby house before returning to true location.

```
var l = new Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ListenerSettings
{
  AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
  ActivityType = Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
  PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false,
  ShowsBackgroundLocationIndicator = false
};
CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += Current_PositionChanged;
CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 0, true, l);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why it happens, but I will close this with "it is what it is".
Where `Plugin.Geolocator` uses network location (now and then) given the setup, I described in the question, using the fused location provider in android (still did not make an iOS implementation) has no such issue, so supposedly `Plugin.Geolocator` is simply outdated and in need of an update.

Fused location provider in Android with these settings work flawlessly

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.Create()
                            .SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityHighAccuracy)
                            .SetInterval(1000)
                            .SetFastestInterval(1000);
```

And its use is described well enough here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location